# Please help the Hebrew Language & Usage Area 51 proposal

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, launch

[Hebrew Language & Usage Proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language?referrer=xh8DHg2W-L6OmdgH5OA4Tw2) is almost there!

Can everyone on this site please go follow and upvote questions that do **not** have 10 upvotes yet in order for us to make this site a reality!

Comment: I personally have already used all my votes there, but I'm concerned that if we artificially push it into beta, it will not be able to stand under its own weight.

Comment: Yes, @HodofHod is right -- artificially pushing this through does the site no favors. :(