# Include Biblical Hebrew

Tags: feature-request, scope, hebrew, language

The [Hebrew](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage?referrer=SKk8-T-LRdtpaSf89lZ05w2) proposal failed, but has been [restarted](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/please-help-the-hebrew-language-usage-area-51-proposal). However, I [don't see why](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/please-help-the-hebrew-language-usage-area-51-proposal) it will do much better. Meanwhile, I hold my self back from asking Hebrew-related questions, out of fear of political down-votes.

I hereby suggest extending the [scope](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/in-what-respects-are-hebrew-language-questions-in-scope) to include biblical Hebrew as its usage and meaning are inseparable from Jewish life and culture. However, modern Hebrew should remain out of scope*. It should also be [considered](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2139/3073) to include other [Jewish languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_languages).

---

<sup>* Except to clarify differences: Why did the staff first become an alligator (*tanin*), and then a snake (*nachash*)? Why the grouping of faith (*emunah*) and national defence (*bitachon*)? – Confusion due to Modern Hebrew's novel definitions for *tanin* and *bitachon*.</sup>

Comment: "Political"? []

Comment: @DoubleAA An agenda to suppress Hebrew here in order to promote the proposed site. I remember seeing such a case, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Could you propose some sample questions for both "on-topic" and "off-topic" under this scheme?  The ends of the scale are easy to see; it's always the fuzzy middle ground that causes problems.

Answer (score 5):

I always thought that biblical Hebrew was on topic. You know, if you have a question about what a word means in a certain Pasuk. I'm pretty sure such questions are left open all the time.

Talmudic Hebrew and Aramaic as well.

Comment: With the caveat that they must identify as such.  A question like "what does אמתלא mean?" has nothing to do with Judaism.  "What is the concept of אמתלא and how is it different than ..." does.

Comment: @YEZ, what about what does אמתלא mean in Mesechta ... Daf ...? I think I have seen that on topic. But when it comes to *biblical* Hebrew, I'm sure.

Comment: Right. As of now every question "about Hebrew language" is [officially](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) off-topic, even if it doesn't get closed.

Comment: I agree.  I just meant as opposed to citing an arbitrary hebrew/aramaic word with no context of why it relates to Judaism.

Comment: @NBZ, if you are asking about a Posuk, it is related to Judaism, which puts it back on topic.

Comment: @NBZ you missed the lead-up line to that line of that post.  They are not on-topic because they are Hebrew.  But _if they relate to Judaism_ then they are not off-topic because they are Hebrew.

Comment: @NBZ No! Please read the beginning of the sentence you've quoted from: "questions unrelated to Judaism ..." Being about Hebrew, whether Biblical, Mishnaic, or Modern, does not make a question on-topic *but also does not make it off-topic*. If the question's about Judaism, it's on-topic. If not, it's not. [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15350088#15350088)'s a handy Venn diagram I made to illustrate this concept, and if you scroll up and down in the chat log there, you'll see other formats of illustration.

Comment: @YEZ and IsaacMoses I think you are right. Maybe that text could be clearer?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Please please please include those diagrams on the scope page! :-D

Comment: @IsaacMoses I remember that :)